# NGINX is not catching the request in production with Ruby on rails + Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have deployed a Ruby on Rails API to AWS ECS with Docker + NGINX configured.
I have followed the link [deploy-web-apps-nginx-to-ecs-with-docker](https://dev.to/sfrancavilla/deploy-web-apps-nginx-to-ecs-with-docker-198i)

I did everything mentioned in above link successfully. When I am trying to hit a request to deployed URI, Getting nothing. I have tried to look at nginx logs but files are not exists at server (connect the AWS instance by ssh).

Can any one help me that

1. How can I find nginx logs at server accessed by ssh?
2. How can I find application's code at server?

Below are the file's content related to docker and nginx configurations.

1. Dockerfile (app)

```
# Retrieve the ruby image
FROM ruby:2.7.1

# Install basic required libs
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev

# Install bundler
RUN gem install bundler --version "2.1.4"

# Set an environment variable for the Rails app root folder
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/vbdapp-assignment

# Create the working directory
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Set working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Set production env variables and enabling the option to serve static files
ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
ENV RACK_ENV='production'

# Add Gemfile
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

# Install gems. -j $(nproc) runs bundle with to total amount of CPU cores/threads available
RUN bundle install -j $(nproc)

# Add Rails project files
COPY . .

# Expose port 3000 to be available for NGINX reverse proxy
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process with Puma
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

2. Dockerfile (web)

```
# Retrieve the nginx base image
FROM nginx

# Install some dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils

# Set env variable where NGINX should look for project files
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/vbdapp-assignment

# Set working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Create log directory
RUN mkdir log

# copy over static assets
COPY public public/

# Copy Nginx config template
COPY /docker/web/nginx.conf /tmp/docker.nginx

RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

# Use the "exec" form of CMD so Nginx shuts down gracefully on SIGTERM (i.e. `docker stop`)
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

3. nginx.conf

```
# 1.Upstream used to define groups of servers, in this case the rails app, that can be referenced by the proxy_pass
upstream rails_app {
    server app:3000;
}

# 2.Server part
server {
   # 2.2.Specify your public IP Address.
   server_name 35.166.220.71;

   # 2.1.Listen to incoming connection on port 80
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 302 http://$server_name$request_uri;


   # 2.3.Specify the public application root
   root   $RAILS_ROOT/public;
   index  index.html;

   # 2.4.Specify where Nginx should write its logs
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   # 2.5.Deny requests for files that should never be accessed such as .rb or .log files
   location ~ /\. {
      deny all;
   }
   location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
      deny all;
   }

   # 2.6.send non-static file requests to the app server
   location / {
      try_files $uri @rails;
   }

   # 2.7.reverse proxy redirecting the request to the rails app, port 3000.
   location @rails {
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://rails_app;
      proxy_read_timeout 900;
   }
}
```

4. docker-compose.yml

```
# 1.Specify the compose file format; we're using the last one.
#   If you're curious, at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/
#   you can find an extensive description on the difference among versions
version: '3'
# 2.Specify the list of services that will be built. In our case, app (Ruby on Rails) and web (NGINX)
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: postgres

  app:
    # Repository URI for our app image
    image: 264434790367.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docker-demo
    build:
      # 2.1.Specify the root path
      context: .
      # 2.2.From the root path defined in context, here we define where the Dockerfile resides
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db

  web:
    # Repository URI for our web image
    image: 264434790367.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docker-demo-web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    # 2.4.Binds port 80 for public connections
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: Maybe you can access to the instance of aws and connect with your docker than run nginx, after access to instance of docker you can search for the logs of nginx and the same way you need follow to find the code of you app

Comment: @JuanseGimenez Thanks for your help. I didn't installed nginx. Now I can access nginx logs. But I am getting default nginx page in url "http://34.222.12.125". I think nginx not sending the request to application. Can you please suggest how should I find the cause of this problem?